# textwrap with ellipsis and nowrap white-space

Tags: html, css

I would like to cut off some long text using an `ellipsis`.

However, with my current implementation, it doesn't include extra words that would cause it to go beyond the `div` and does not show `ellipsis` to indicate that the text is cut off.

**What am I doing wrong?**

http://jsfiddle.net/sw6Sp/6/

```
<div class="testWrap">This is some very long text that I want to cut off </div>

.testWrap{
    max-width: 125px;
    height:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow_hover ??

Comment: You haven't updated your jsfiddle yet...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use [**`text-overflow: ellipsis`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) along with [**`white-space: nowrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw6Sp/5/)

```
.testWrap {
    width: 125px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: whoops, thanks for the comment.  so adding white-space worked!  I'll accept your answer in 10 min (when I can)

Answer (score 5):

Adding the css-rule `white-space: nowrap;` should solve your problem.

```
<div class="testWrap" style="
    max-width: 125px;
    height:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
">This is some very long text that I want to cut off </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ellipsis without `white-space: nowrap`, use these CSS rules

```
white-space: pre-line;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```